# Как правильно настроить подключение в Toad for Oracle?

Tags: oracle

скачал и поставил жабу, пока в ней ничего не смыслю кроме того что сам язык SQL знаю давно, но саму прогу нет.
ввожу такие данные:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и отображается такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

помогите разобраться как мне запустить это приложение.

Comment: Написано же в сообшении об ошибке: нет прослушивателя на локальном хосте. Пробуйте сначала с SQL*Plus.

Comment: думаешь я знаю как туда зайти я не смыслю в этом приложении

Comment: @vlad_12, здесь вопрос не в приложении. У вас не настроен прослушиватель на вашей машине. Настройте прослушиватель oracle для начала.